# Formule de politesse

Tags: syntaxe, politesse

Est-ce plus correct de dire :

> Si vous avez besoin d'un quelconque autre document je reste disponible.

ou bien:

> Si vous avez besoin de quoi que ce soit d'autre je reste disponible.

Y'a t-il une formulation plus correcte/professionnelle pour exprimer cette idée ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La seconde forme est presque correcte mais pas la première. La première se rectifie comme suit (une possibilité parmi d'autres), de sorte à exprimer ce que l'on comprend quand même malgré la syntaxe défectueuse ;

> 1 Si vous avez besoin d'un autre document, quel qu'il soit, je reste à votre disposition.
>
> 2 Si vous avez besoin de quoi que ce soit d'autre, je reste à votre disposition.

Les deux sont correctes et très acceptables chez les professionnels ; il faut cependant remplacer « disponible » par « à votre disposition ». La raison est que « disponible » signifie « qui, n'ayant aucune contrainte, aucune obligation matérielle, dispose librement de son temps », ce qui ne correspond pas exactement ; il ne s'agit que d'être prêt à faire le nécessaire de sorte que les document soient envoyés *lorsque* demandé, en d'autres mots il s'agit d' « Assurer quelqu'un de son aide, de son dévouement, de son désir de lui être agréable », dans les mots du TLFi.

La forme à choisir dépend de ce sur quoi on veut insister ; si l'on veut que la personne soit assurée que n'importe quel document réclamé sera envoyé c'est la première possibilité qui convient. Si on veut sous-entendre quelque chose de plus divers que seulement des documents, pourvu que le contexte s'y prête, la seconde est celle qui convient. S'il ne s'agit que de documents, il vaut mieux rester spécifique et utiliser la première forme ; cependant la seconde, d'un style moins souhaitable, ira aussi.

ADDITION

Aucune explication n'a été donné pour la suppression de la forme « quelconque autre » dans le texte ci-dessus et si on pense bien à ce qui pourrait rendre cette combinaison inacceptable on ne voit pas vraiment ce qui serait illogique, ce qui pourrait constituer une relation bizarre. Je l'ai supprimée parce n'étant que très peu usitée elle fait une impression étrange, pas naturelle ; en fait, elle a été utilisée par le passé mais depuis 1925 à peu près la [fréquence d'utilisation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quelconque+autre+*&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cquelconque%20autre%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20cause%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20qu%27un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20chose%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20mani%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20qu%27une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20personne%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20pays%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20forme%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cquelconque%20autre%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20cause%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20qu%27un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20chose%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20mani%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20qu%27une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20personne%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20pays%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquelconque%20autre%20forme%3B%2Cc0) n'a pas cessé de baisser, de sorte que de nos jours elle est près d'être nulle. Il ne faut donc pas considérer son utilisation comme véritablement une faute. Je pense devoir l'éviter moi-même, mais si on y tient absolument elle est encore utilisable.

Comment: Merci pour les détails apportés !

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que la formule formelle dans ce genre de situation est

> **Je reste à votre disposition** si vous avez besoin d'un autre document.

Answer (score 1):

Deux variations (non locuteur natif du français) :

> Je reste/demeure à votre entière disposition pour tout complément d'information ou pièce que vous pourriez souhaiter.
>
> Je me tiens à votre disposition pour tout renseignement complémentaire.